# Empathy not opening on correct tag in Awesome-WM

Tags: awesome-wm

I have created a rule for my instant messenger, empathy, to always start on the "im" tag.

```
{ rule = { class = "Empathy" },
    properties = { tag = tags[1][5] } },
```

At the end of rc.lua, I auto-start it using:

```
awful.util.spawn("/usr/bin/empathy")
```

However, when restarting Aweseome-WM, the window always opens on the first tag.

Other programs work just fine:

```
    { rule = { class = "Firefox" },
        properties = { tag = tags[1][1] } },
    { rule = { class = "Codeblocks" },
        properties = { tag = tags[1][2] } },
```

I found someone describing the same problem [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.awesome/6988), and tried what was suggested (checking the window's class in an event) and I also checked the window's class using xprop, both methods tell me that "Empathy" is the correct class.

```
c:connect_signal("property::class", function(c)
        naughty.notify({ text = "CHANGED name!" .. c.class })
    end)
```

How can I make empathy appear on the "im" tag?

Comment: I just noticed: When changing the rule and adding a width and height to the client like so: `properties = { tag = tags[1][5], floating = true },
      callback = function( c )
                   c:geometry( { width = 300 , height = 800 } )
               end
   },` then the width and height get set correctly... so the class name is recognized - meaning the issue must be something else.

Comment: Create a simple callback function which show the new client's properties. The `xprop` isn't good because maybe something changed.

Comment: I added this line: `naughty.notify({text = c.class .. ": " .. c.name})` to the mouse::enter signal. It displays **Empathy: Contact List** when I hover the mouse over the client. So this works fine. Also, when I add: `awful.client.movetotag(tags[1][tagIdByName("im")])` to the same signal, the client gets moved to the im tag, just like I want it. But at the start, using either "properties" or "callback" in a rul (as displayed above) this doesn't work. The width and height changes, but it's not moved to another tag.

Comment: I noticed something else: The rule works, when starting empathy manually, later during the session. Just not at startup.